# Spring SseEmitter throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable converter for class error when sending a DTO object

Tags: java, spring, jackson, server-sent-events

On our Spring-boot application, we have the following simple `SseStatusDto` DTO:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SseStatusDto {

    private String currentPhase;
    private int percentage;
    private String result;
}
```

For some reason which I cannot understand, Spring cannot convert this DTO into a JSON while trying to send the info back to the client:

```
emitter.send(SseEmitter.event()
                    .data(SseStatusDto.builder()
                            .currentPhase("DONE")
                            .percentage(100)
                            .result("temp-result")
                            .build()), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable converter for class <class>`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding getter and setter for `SseStatusDto` model:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructo
@Getter
@Setter
public class SseStatusDto {

  private String currentPhase;
  private int percentage;
  private String result;
}
```

This should solve your issue.